# tell about vs. tell of

Tags: meaning

Are both of this sentences right? Do they mean exactly the same thing? If no: What is the difference or which of them is wrong. And which version is wrong, if there is?

> The old walls of this castle tell stories of love and revenge.

> The old walls of this castle tell stories about love and revenge.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical and mean almost the same thing, but the "of" is more emphatic.

A biography of someone called, say, Peter could be referred to as

> The story of Peter

but using "about"

> The story about Peter

does not sound right, it would imply the *only* story, and

> A story about Peter

is weak, and possibly describes one novel of a series featuring Peter.

So I would say that your first sentence

> The old walls of this castle tell stories of love and revenge.

has a bit more dramatic effect than the second sentence.

Comment: I agree with you - *"of" is more emphatic.* But I don't know why, and I can't seem to be able to find a source that substantiates this - but I have only been looking for 2 minutes.